# & sign inside batch file parameter to be passed for another program

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that I call with something like this

```
call do.cmd "one two"
```

In `do.cmd` I am launching a program and pass to it first parameter from above:

```
@echo off
some_program.exe -name='%1'
```

The value to `some_program.exe` for `name` variable **must** be passed inside single quotes without surrounding double quotes. To get rid of double quotes in passed parameter I make a temporary variable like this:

```
set v_tmp=%1
set v_tmp=%v_artist:"=%
```

And then launch my program by

```
some_programm.exe -name='%v_tmp%'
```

The problem start when with `do.cmd` some text having `&` sign is passed. If I leave batch file code as is, variaable setting will fail because `&` will act as a divider. If I escape `&` sign by

```
set v_tmp=%1
set v_tmp=%v_tmp:&"=^^^&%
set v_tmp=%v_tmp:"=%
```

then `some_program` will output text having `^&`..

The question is how do I get from `call do.cmd "one & two"` line to the correct `&` sign escaping and double quote removal so that to have in result `some_program.exe -name='one & two'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use delayed expansion here.

```
@echo off
set "arg1=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
some_program.exe -name='!arg1!'
```

This works, as `%~1` removes enclosing quotes, if present.
And `!arg1!` always expands the variable in a safe manner.